# Unneccesary right padding in LongListSelector Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am developing an application in which I use longlistselector. I have two code bases 1 for wp7 and another for wp8 but my long list selector is giving a right padding in the item seperator I created and same code is working fine on wp7 .

my code for longlistselctor is

```
 <controls:LongListSelector Margin="30,30,30,30"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  x:Name="listofintroductions"
                Background="White" Visibility="{Binding Hotintrovisibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" ItemsSource="{Binding introductions, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}">
                <controls:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="100">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="/Images/flame.png" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Width="40" Margin="26.5,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Hot Introductions" Foreground="#404041" FontFamily="/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf#Helvetica Neue"  FontSize="25.5" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Grid Height="2" Background="#E6E6E6" Width="480" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                <controls:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="viewallintros" Tap="viewallintros_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="View all potential intros" FontFamily="/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf#Helvetica Neue"  FontSize="25" Padding="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#404041"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
                <controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="hotintrotemplate" Tap="hotintrotemplate_Tap" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="nameintro" Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="25.5" FontFamily="/Fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.ttf#Helvetica Neue" Foreground="#4EBEC7" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="30,19,0,3"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="introid" Text="{Binding Contactid}" Height="0" Width="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding number_introduction}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="25.5" Foreground="#83D96F" FontFamily="/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf#Helvetica Neue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0,19,30,3"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf#Helvetica Neue" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="19.5" Foreground="#404041" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="30,3,30,3"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company_name}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="18" FontFamily="/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf#Helvetica Neue" Foreground="#d5d5d5" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="30,3,30,3"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="34,0,34,0">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Image Source="/Images/icon_linkedin@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform" Visibility="{Binding linkdenicon}" Height="20" Margin="0,9,10,9" />
                                    <Image Source="/Images/icon_twitter@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform" Visibility="{Binding twittericon}" Height="20" Margin="0,9,10,9" />
                                    <Image Source="/Images/icon_facebook@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform" Visibility="{Binding facebookicon}" Height="20" Margin="0,9,10,9" />
                                    <Image Source="/Images/icon_web_link@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform" Visibility="{Binding googleplusicon}" Height="20" Margin="0,9,10,9" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="4" Height="2" Width="480" Background="#E6E6E6" Margin="-30,20,-30,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:LongListSelector>
```

as you can see I have made a grid with height 2 pixel as a item seperator but it looks likes this ...

[image]

you can see the right padding in the item seperator. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 13):

I've had the same issue as described above. I noticed that this issue only occurs when there are more items on the list than can be shown on screen. I found out that it was the VerticalScrollBar that created the issue. When the VerticalScrollBar is not required (there are not enough items in the list) the scroll-bar is 'Collapsed' and the items are aligned to the right correctly. 
So.. you would think that setting the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Collapsed` would fix the issue, right? Well `Collapsed` isn't an option for some reason. Something like `Hidden` or `Disabled` might also do the trick? Too bad. That won't work either.

Searching the web I found a rather nice workaround for the issue.
The following blog explains the issue and the workaround: http://y2bd.me/blog/2013/10/31/fixing-the-long-list-selectors-scrollbar-spacing-issue/

As the link may be removed I'll duplicate the solution here too.

The author of the blog created a style for the `LongListSelector` that "extracts" the VerticalScrollBar from the selector and let the ScrollBar "hover" above the list.

So in your ResourceDictionary you add the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="LLSFloatingScrollbarStyle"
           TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
<Setter Property="Background"
        Value="Transparent" />
<Setter Property="Foreground"
        Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  d:DesignWidth="480"
                  d:DesignHeight="800">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5" />
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                 To="1"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                    <ViewportControl x:Name="ViewportControl"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                    <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                               Margin="4,0,-12,0"
                               Opacity="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Orientation="Vertical" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Finally on the LongListSelector you add the style reference like below and you're ready to go!

```
<phone:LongListSelector Style="{StaticResource LLSFloatingScrollbarStyle}" />
```

Special thanks and credits to the author of the blog.

Comment: Holy cow it worked like charm. nice style template you got there, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem just had to change the style of the longlistselector and remove the space given for vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Could you please mention which exact property you changed and to what value?